# How to embbed a matrix symbolic form from sympy in a formatted string?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, string-formatting, sympy

In a notebook, printing a sympy matrix is not difficult

[image]

However this doesn't work for formatted strings:

[image]

How can I do to maintain the symbolic representation in the formatted string?

---

Textual code:

```py
import sympy
sympy.init_printing()
C = sympy.Matrix([[2, 3], [4, 5]])
display (C)
display (f'{C} x {C} = {C*C}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [1]: C = Matrix([[2,3],[4,5]])

In [2]: C
Out[2]: 
⎡2  3⎤
⎢    ⎥
⎣4  5⎦
```

The `f'{}'` formating uses either the `repr` or `str` format of the `C` object:

```
In [3]: repr(C)
Out[3]: 'Matrix([\n[2, 3],\n[4, 5]])'

In [4]: str(C)
Out[4]: 'Matrix([[2, 3], [4, 5]])'
```

It's a python formatting operation that doesn't pay attention to `sympy's` display methods.

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html documents `sympy` printing, though I don't off hand see ideas that will help you.

To display the whole thing as a sympy expression, the whole thing has to be rendered as whole; we can't forat each piece separately:

```
In [9]: display(C, 'x', C, '=', C*C)
⎡2  3⎤
⎢    ⎥
⎣4  5⎦
'x'
⎡2  3⎤
⎢    ⎥
⎣4  5⎦
'='
⎡16  21⎤
⎢      ⎥
⎣28  37⎦
```

===

As per comment:

```
In [11]: Eq(MatMul(C, C), C*C)
Out[11]: 
⎡2  3⎤ ⎡2  3⎤   ⎡16  21⎤
⎢    ⎥⋅⎢    ⎥ = ⎢      ⎥
⎣4  5⎦ ⎣4  5⎦   ⎣28  37⎦
```

Comment: That's too bad, I was expecting SymPy would provide a replacement for `t'string'` to manage it's own specifics.

Comment: The `f'string'` feature in python is quite new, so I wouldn't expect third party packages to emulate it.   https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html is a more detailed printing document.

Comment: Thanks for the link which talks about many aspects of printing at one place. Considering the past attempts and their number as well as the complexity introduced by math and latex, I've no hope either it can be solved quickly.

Comment: You can just display `Eq(MatMul(C, C), C*C)`